# how to read the values from viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, paging, viewstate

In asp.net gridview, which is paging enabled. page size is 10. checkboxes state is maintaing when multiple checkboxes are checked. but the problem is when we clcik submit only current page selected records only added to the list. i want entiere gridview seleted records to be added.

```
protected void gvFiling_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (gvFiling.Rows.Count > 0 && ViewState["datakeys"] != null) 
    {
        List < object > datakeys = (List < object > ) ViewState["datakeys"];
        foreach(GridViewRow row in gvFiling.Rows)
        ((CheckBox) row.FindControl("cbxApply")).Checked = datakeys.Contains(gvFiling.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
    }
}
protected void FullPostBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List < DataKey > applyList = new List < DataKey > ();
    //there are 30 records. each page is having 10 records. selected checkbox records in the current page only added to list
    //requirment is add the selected records from 3 pages.
    foreach(GridViewRow row in gvFiling.Rows) 
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) row.FindControl("cbxApply");
        if (cb != null) if (cb.Checked) applyList.Add(gvFiling.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]);
    }

    if (applyList.Count > 0) 
    {
        GB.TLS.Business.ServiceHandler.FERCDocket.TariffFiling_DocketSearch_ApplyAssociations(applyList, this.AssociatedObjectType, this.AssociatedRecordID, SessionWrapper.UserModel.UserId);
        gvFiling.DataBind();
    }
    if (ApplyFiling != null) ApplyFiling();
    mpeSearch.Hide();
}
```

protected void gvFiling_PageIndexChanging(Object sender,GridViewPageEventArgs e) 
    {
        List < object > datakeys = ViewState["datakeys"] != null ? (List < object > ) ViewState["datakeys"] : new List < object > ();
        //Add checked DataKeys
        foreach(GridViewRow row in gvFiling.Rows)
        if (((CheckBox) row.FindControl("cbxApply")).Checked) datakeys.Add(gvFiling.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
        else datakeys.Remove(gvFiling.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
        ViewState["datakeys"] = datakeys;
    }

Comment: _[Wall of code hits you for 10 damage!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_.   _[Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_